# Flutter can't connect to iOS simulator

Tags: flutter, dart

I created first flutter app on Mac.

but I can't build it on iOS simulator.
when I build it;
an iOS simulator will run.
and wait.

vs Code say to me;

-Cannot launch without an active device

-Failed to launch iOS Simulator: Error: Emulator didn't connect within 60 seconds

IDE : vs Code

my Macbook : MacBook Pro 2011 early

macOs version : high Sierra

flutter version : 13.8

xcode version : 9.4

Comment: When you open the project in xcode (select the ios map and preferably the .xcworkspace) and then try to build it to e.g. the iphone 8? Any difference?

Comment: I tried and build it.

I need upgrade xcode version.
I m trying xcode 10.3 install to high Sierra.

Comment: You can still build the ios version by running is in xcode. Not necessary to do it in AS / VS. (Also I believe High Sierra cannot be upgraded to a higher xcode version.)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Open Xcode and go to preferences - > locations - > Command Line Tools and select Xcode 10 or above

Comment: Nice! It works. I'm using latest version of xCode (12.1).

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you

Comment: I did this, and already had 14.3 set. But set it again, and VS Code was once again able to detect my physical iOS devices. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

at the first run bellow command

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

and then

```
sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
```

after than run "flutter devices"
now you see ios simulators if running

Answer (score 4):

I have also same issue 
follow these instruciton:

```
Xcode -> Prefrences -> locations -> select your command line tols
```

[image: Follow the image]

Answer (score 2):

Which device do you use as a Simulator? From the [docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#set-up-the-ios-simulator):

> Make sure your simulator is using a 64-bit device (iPhone 5s or later)
> by checking the settings in the simulator’s Hardware > Device menu.

Run `flutter doctor`. Are there any errors?

Comment: hi.  
i chosed iPhone x

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. Flutter doesn't see any simulators.
Flutter required now Xcode 10.2 minimum. You can't run 10.2 on high sierra, therefore use flatter.

Comment: I did run 10.2 on high Sierra. look my blog page : www.onurbozkurt.com.tr 

it's Turkish but if u look images u can understand.
it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

I have also same issue
follow these instruciton:

**Xcode -> Prefrences -> locations -> select your command line tols**

Same process we can check in video:-
https://youtu.be/2HnOWSC-yaM

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple Xcode and don't have Xcode With default name "Xcode", this problem may occur. Try to rename one of xcode to "Xcode"

Answer (score 0):

The major issue is with XCode. To quickly fix the issue, open project on XCode(make sure you choose the /ios path inside your flutter project.) and Open Preferences. On preferences dialog, go to Location and choose a command line tool from given option.
Restart your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (with VS Code) I just had to quit the simulator app in my dock and select the simulator again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem , also I've been trying to solve it with all these solutions here, I solved it when I I deleted ios folder and wrote `flutter create .` in the terminal

Answer (score -2):

I had many problems with flutter stable version before,
Try to change it to Dev version